# invalid fullname must end in a custom suffix(for ex. _c)

Tags: community, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin

Added AccountContactRelation object inside my DX unlocked package but while versioning getting error
**invalid fullname must end in a custom suffix(for ex. _c)”**

What is the issue for this?please advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your SFDX Project file must contain a reference to a definition file:

```
{
  "packageDirectories": [
    {
      "path": "force-app",
      "package": "my-package-name",
      "versionName": "ver 0.1",
      "versionNumber": "0.1.0.NEXT",
      "default": true,
      "definitionFile": "config/scratch-features.json"
    }
  ],
  "namespace": "",
  "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
  "sourceApiVersion": "47.0"
}
```

This file must contain the settings that the package depends on:

```
{
   "settings": {
       "accountSettings": {
           "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true
       }
   }
}
```

After this, you'll be allowed to upload other metadata that depends on this setting.

You can also use this configuration file to spin up a new scratch org that has all the required extra features turned on for all of your packages to install/deploy/push successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ..its working now. is there any salesforce url which I can refer for future?

Comment: @Ananga https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm

Comment: Thanks !! Its really helpful..

Comment: Hi, I am facing similar issue for LiveChatTranscript object.Can you pls tell me which setting I should mention instead of "accountsetting"

Comment: @Ananga I think [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/48/LiveChatDeployment/scratch-def/developer) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you pls let me know whether I should mention below setting for LiveChatTranscript object:{
   "settings": {
       "LiveChatDeployment": {
           "enableTranscriptSave": true
       }
   }
}

Comment: @Ananga According to the Metadata Coverage Report, you don't need that setting. Also, all settings are now in camelCase, not TitleCase. Go ahead and try it, and let me know.

Comment: tried with   "settings": {
        "liveChatDeployment": {
            "enableTranscriptSave": true
        }
     } but got error ::: The object 'LiveChatDeployment' of type Settings metadata does not exist.

Comment: even though my scratch org is based on an orgShape that I just created from our "Production" DevHub org.. I'm still having to play around with these settings. Maybe this is part of orgShape being in beta still