# AccountContactRelation won't deploy to Scratch Org even with feature enabled in Scratch Org Definition

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I am trying to migrate my team to scratch orgs from individual dev sandboxes.  The final barrier seems to be the fact that we're using the `AccountContactRelation` object.  Whenever I do a push to a scratch org the first error I get is:

```
Error    force-app\main\default\objects\AccountContactRelation\AccountContactRelation.object-meta.xml      Invalid fullName, must end in a custom suffix ( for ex. __c )
```

I also get errors like:

```
Error    force-app\main\default\classes\AccountContact_RelationTriggerHandler.cls                   Invalid type: AccountContactRelation (14:13)
```

So the object clearly is not in the org.  Below is my `project-scratch-def.json` file.

```
{
  "orgName": "Lazard Scratch",
  "sourceOrg": "00D1N000001i9f2UAA",
  "features": [
    "AuthorApex",
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "DevelopmentWave",
    "FieldAuditTrail",
    "Interaction",
    "MultiCurrency",
    "ProcessBuilder",
    "StateAndCountryPicklist",
    "Workflow",
    "WorkflowFlowActionFeature"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "accountSettings": {
      "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true
    },
    "activitiesSettings": {
      "allowUsersToRelateMultipleContactsToTasksAndEvents":true
    },
    "entitlementSettings": {
      "enableEntitlements": true
    },
    "lightningExperienceSettings": {
      "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "languageSettings": {
      "enableTranslationWorkbench":  true,
      "enableEndUserLanguages": true
    },
    "mobileSettings": {
      "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
    },
    "nameSettings":{
      "enableMiddleName": true,
      "enableNameSuffix": true
    },
    "quoteSettings": {
      "enableQuote": true
    },
    "territory2Settings": {
      "enableTerritoryManagement2": true
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I should be doing differently to allow this object to deploy?

Comment: Does this post answer your question- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296952/invalid-fullname-must-end-in-a-custom-suffixfor-ex-c

Comment: That might have something to do with it.  The VSC extension seems to be hiding the error `Warning: If you're using Contacts to Multiple Accounts, beginning with the Spring ’21 release, the feature isn't automatically enabled. You must manually enable the setting for new scratch orgs. Enable the setting in 
one of these ways: update the Account Settings page in Setup, add the enableRelateContactsToMultipleAccounts setting to your scratch org definition file, or enable it via Metadata API.` when deploying, but I see it when I type the command myself.  I'm trying again now but getting timeouts.

Comment: This resolves my error with deploying the `AccountContactRelation` so thanks very much for that.  However I still get other errors related to that object, for example `Error    force-app\main\default\flexipages\UltimateParentConsultant.flexipage-meta.xml                                                       Component [force:relatedListSingleContainer] attribute [relatedListApiName]: Could not find related list [AccountContactRelations] for entity [Account]`

Comment: I've also verified that the feature for `Allow users to relate a contact to multiple accounts` has been enabled in the scratch org, but now I can't see the `AccountContactRelation` object in object manager so the build still fails.

Comment: I have been facing the same issue. Going to the org and manually disabling it and enabling it again fixes the issue, but it's not a great workaround.
I have posted something that is related to this issue:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/388128/didnt-understand-relationship-taskrelations-allow-users-to-relate-multiple

Answer (score 1):

I think this is linked to a Known Issue (two actually, but I assume the root cause is the same) where the `AccountContactRelation` feature is randomly not activated on Scratch Orgs:

- https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001s8OlQAI
- https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000001PYYlQAO