# Didn't understand relationship 'TaskRelations' - Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, taskrelation

Does anyone know how to fix that? What am I missing here?

I need to access the `TaskRelations` object on my scratch org. AFAIK, it should be available when the **Allow Users to Relate Multiple Contacts to Tasks and Events** feature is enabled (Setup > Sales > Activity Settings).

It shows **Feature enabled**, but the checkbox is not checked.

[image]

When running tests I can see the following error:

```
System.QueryException: Didn't understand relationship 'TaskRelations' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

These are the main entries part of the **sfdx-project.json** config:

```
...
"features": [
    "SharedActivities"
],
"settings": {
    "accountSettings": {
        "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true
    },
    ...
}
...
```

This is how it looks like on a Sandbox where it works as expected, note that the checkbox is checked:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked internally and seems like a known issue described [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001s8OlQAI). People have got fair bit of success using the Feature and settings both in scratch-def.json as shown below

```
{
 "orgName": "Mo",
 "edition": "Developer",
 "features": ["EnableSetPasswordInApi","ContactsToMultipleAccounts"],
 "settings": {
  "lightningExperienceSettings": {
     "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
  },
   "accountSettings": {
      "enableRelateContactToMultipleAccounts": true
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mohith Shrivastava! I had that in place along with other features, but it's a good observation. Unfortunately that's not a final fix because I noticed that it's intermittent.
Someone has already created this known issue, which is what is affecting me.
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001s8OlQAI